# Is there a way to trim a String variable from a certain set of characters to another without specifying its location?

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a large value on a String variable, I want to keep just some of it, I don't know the exact position in the String in which my data is located as it could vary any time, but I know it's in between specific tags, so how could I keep only what's inside those tags?

Example of the kind of string I have:

```
Dim var as String = "
<random>     <stuffIDontNeed>      <x>1</x>      <x>2</x>      <x>3</x>     
</stuffIDontNeed>     <stuffIDoNeed>      <x>a</x>      <x>b</x>      <x>c</x>   
</stuffIDoNeed>    </random> "
```

It's all inside the same String I just used multiple lines so it showed fully without scrolling.

So what I want to do is to get everything from where stuffIDoNeed starts to where it ends, tags and everything not only the values in them.

Comment: Use IndexOf.  As long as there is no more than one occurrence of stuffIDoNeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will extract the substring from the input string (Please don't use var as variable name, it is confusing)

```
Dim inputData as String = " " & _
        "<random>     <stuffIDontNeed>      <x>1</x>      <x>2</x>      <x>3</x>      " & _
        "</stuffIDontNeed>     <stuffIDoNeed>      <x>a</x>      <x>b</x>      <x>c</x>   "  & _
        "</stuffIDoNeed>    </random> " 

Dim result as string = string.Empty
Dim startPos = inputData.IndexOf("<stuffIDoNeed>")
Dim endPos = inputData.IndexOf("</stuffIDoNeed>")
if startPos > 0 AndAlso endPos > 0 andAlso endPos > startPos then
    result = inputData.SubString(startPos, endPos + 15 - startPos)
end if

Console.WriteLine(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [String.IndexOf Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method.

```
Dim var as String = "<random>     <stuffIDontNeed>      <x>1</x>      <x>2</x>     <x>3</x>     </stuffIDontNeed>     <stuffIDoNeed>      <x>a</x>      <x>b</x>      <x>c</x>  </stuffIDoNeed>    </random> "

Dim Start As Integer = var.IndexOf("<stuffIDoNeed>")
Dim End As Integer = var.IndexOf("</stuffIDoNeed>") + 15

Dim var NewString = var.SubString(Start, End - Start)
```

Grab the position in the string that `<stuffIDoNeed>` starts at.

Next, grab the position in the string that `</stuffIDoNeed>` starts at, then add 15 to it to account for the end of the text you are looking for.

Finally, use Substring with the Start position, and the End - Start to get the length of the string to extract.

`NewString` will equal `<stuffIDoNeed>      <x>a</x>      <x>b</x>      <x>c</x>  </stuffIDoNeed>`.

Alternatively, if you're planning on doing something with the values in the string you extract, you can look at LINQ to XML and use an XDocument to load the XML and parse it out that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the value of a node in an XML document, it is far better to use one of the the built in XML document parsers in .NET such as `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`.  For instance, here's how you would do it with `XmlDocument`:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(var)
Dim stuffIDoNeed As String = doc.SelectSingleNode("/random/stuffIDoNeed").InnerXml
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to convert to XML, if you know your structure will always be like that. Otherwise use Regex, you can then adapt if it becomes more complex. It is also much more readable than `IndexOf` approach. For example:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
.....
Dim var As String = "<random>     <stuffIDontNeed>      <x>1</x>      <x>2</x>      <x>3</x>     </stuffIDontNeed>     <stuffIDoNeed>      <x>a</x>      <x>b</x>      <x>c</x>   </stuffIDoNeed>    </random> "
Dim g As Match = Regex.Match(var, "<stuffIDoNeed>(?<stuffIDoNeed>.*)</stuffIDoNeed>")
MsgBox(g.Groups("stuffIDoNeed").Value)
```